# How could a considerable increase in loss leads to an improvement in accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy

I'm experimenting with NLP and at the moment, I'm trying to come up with a translator model for converting English sentences to French counterparts. I'm using this dataset (not that it's relevant):

https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/raw/master/language-translation/data

which is composed of more than 137K sentences. My model is an encoder-decoder LSTM with attention implemented in Keras. And here are my plotted validation loss and accuracy charts:

[image]

[image]

The two accuracy metrics are custom ones developed by myself. But they are based on the same `categorical_accuracy` from Keras.

Now, my question is why I'm getting an improvement for the accuracy while the loss value is getting wrose?

Also, is such a model trustworthy?

Comment: Are you sure your loss is not in fact the *negative* of what you show here?

Comment: @desertnaut I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Check whether padded values get accounted while computing accuracy, which shouldn't be the case. You should create mask for padded values and use that while computing accuracy. For instance, while the y_true value for padded region is 0, and 0 as well for y_pred, then y_true == y_pred counts as a correct prediction and impacts the overall accuracy. This is wrong, and what you should instead do is define a custom accuracy metric that does the following:

```
correct = y_pred == y_true
mask = tf.cast(tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool), tf.int16)
accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(correct * mask)/tf.reduce_sum(mask)
```

Hopefully this should give you a correct measure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the reason in **your** case. But in general larger (worse) `log_loss` could correspond to a larger (better) `accuracy` **if** resulting probabilities are uncalibrated:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss, accuracy_score

random = np.random.RandomState(41)
y = np.array([0]*50 + [1]*50)

probas1= np.concatenate([[0]*30, random.uniform(size=40), [1]*30])
probas2= np.concatenate([random.normal(loc=0.48, scale=0.01, size=50),
                         random.normal(loc=0.52, scale=0.01, size=50)])

print(log_loss(y, probas1), accuracy_score(y, probas1>0.5))
print(log_loss(y, probas2), accuracy_score(y, probas2>0.5))

>>> 0.31286642799863323 0.83
>>> 0.6536974952243071 0.99

plt.hist(y, label='True classes');
plt.hist(probas1, label='Better log_loss, worse accuracy')
plt.hist(probas2, label='Worse log_loss, better accuracy')
plt.legend()
```

[image: hist]